# I am trying to align placeholder text to the top with css

Tags: html, css

I am making a web application that has a body for writing things and I added a placeholder, the body is pretty large in height which makes the placeholder get center-aligned to the left. I need a way to get it to align to the top on the left. This is my css code for the input and placeholder:

```
    font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}

.desc-input input {
   border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 1039px;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 500px;
}

.desc-input .placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  bottom: 50%;
  top: 90px;  
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: calc(100% - 24px);  
  color: #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

}
```

This is my html code for the input and placeholder:

```
<div class="desc-input">
                    <input type="desc" placeholder="Write the description of your job..." />

                  </div>
```

Comment: why you are not using a textarea for such a large input? as it is it is meant to be ;) 
an input will always be single line, even if it is 500px height. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::placeholder` pseudo-selector that will help you style the placeholder of the input element. `.placeholder` won't apply the styling to the placeholder.

The CSS is:

```
  .desc-input input {
        border: none;
       -webkit-appearance: none;
       -ms-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 12px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        width: 1039px;
       font-size: 14px;
       height: 500px;
  }


  input::placeholder {
     position: absolute;
     left: 12px;
     bottom: 50%;
     top: 90px;  
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     width: calc(100% - 24px);  
     color: #aaa;
     overflow: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;

  }
```

This will apply the CSS styling to the placeholder.
Additionally , you can remove the `bottom` property rule from the placeholder styling. The `top` property is sufficient to align the placeholder at the top and you can align it using **percentage(%)** or **px** or other units as desired.

```
 input::placeholder {
     position: absolute;
     left: 12px;
     top: 10%;  
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     width: calc(100% - 24px);  
     color: #aaa;
     overflow: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;

 }
```